# Is there any possible way to keep comments at a single place if it is repetitive?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, comments, editor

I don't know but is there any possible way to keep comments at a single place if it is repetitive, in visual studio editor?

Or something like to create link in comments and if we click on that link and it jumps to bunch of commented code, so we can just write the link where it is needed to write that bunch of code. So no repetitive comments are written.

Comment: i'm not sure that it's possible, but i shouldn't do that. If an other programmer wants to understand your code, he/she has to click each time on it to read the comment. And if VS is supporting it, people who is writing with other IDE's could face with an non-understandable comment.

Answer (score 0):

The C# compiler allows you to reference an external XML file which contains the actual comments for a method.  To do this you use an `<include>` element in the XML doc comment

```
/// <include file='file.doc' path='Parent/Child[@name="member"]/*' />
```

The contents of `file.doc` need to be an XML file and the comment for that method be at the XML path described in the `path` element

```
<Parent>
  <Child name="member">
    <summary>The actual comment</summary>
  </Child>
</Parent>
```

More information is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h8dy30z.aspx)

I do not know if Visual Studio will allow you to click and follow through to the documentation.  But the correct summary will be emitted in the file XML doc file for the assembly